# Any segment can't be inside the sphere

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove if two points $a$ and $b$ are in the closed ball, then the segment between them is inside the ball, and can't be in the sphere, in another words:

Let $a,b\in \mathbb R^n$, $a\neq b$ with the norm induced by the inner product. If $|a|\le r$ and $|b|\le r$, then $|(1-t)a+tb|\lt r$, for every $t\in (0,1)$.

**My attempt of solution:**

$|(1-t)a+tb|\le (1-t)|a|+t|b|\le (1-t)r+tr= r$

But why does this inequality is restrict ($\lt$)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That third $\leq$ should be an equality, which gives you one less place to look for an inequality to be strict.

Comment: @Semiclassical yes, my mistake, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a$ is not in the sphere, then $\|a\| < r$ so the desired inequality follows from what you've written; likewise if $b$ is not in the sphere. Therefore, suppose both $a$ and $b$ are in the sphere and are distinct; if $a = b$, the line between them is degenerate.

If $\|(1-t)a+tb\| < (1-t)\|a\| + t\|b\|$, then you're done, so you just need to deal with the case where $\|(1-t)a+tb\| = (1-t)\|a\| + t\|b\|$; i.e. when the triangle inequality gives an equality. Luckily, we know exactly when this happens: $\|x + y\| \leq \|x\| + \|y\|$ with equality if and only if one of $x$ or $y$ is a non-negative scalar multiple of the other. Therefore, $(1 - t)a = \lambda tb$ and for any $t \neq 0, 1$, we see that $a = kb$ where $k = \frac{\lambda t}{1-t}$. As $a$ and $b$ lie on the sphere, the only possible values of $k$ are $\pm 1$ (you should check this), but as $a \neq b$, we see that $a = -b$. But then

$$\|(1-t)a + tb\| = \|(t-1)b+tb\| = \|(2t - 1)b\| = |2t-1|\|b\| = |2t - 1|r.$$

As $-1 < 2t - 1 < 1$ for $t \in (0, 1)$, we're done.

**Added Later:** Above I claimed that $\|x+y\| = \|x\| + \|y\|$ if and only if one of $x$ or $y$ is a non-negative scalar multiple of the other. This is not true in general, but is true for a norm of a normed vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ induced by an inner product. More generally, it is true if and only if the normed space is *strictly convex*, i.e. the unit ball is strictly convex. What this exercise shows is that if the norm of a normed space is induced by an inner product, then the normed space is a strictly convex space.

Note, this may seem like circular reasoning upon first glance, but it isn't. If the norm on a normed vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ is induced by an inner product there is a proof of the fact "$\|x+y\| = \|x\|+\|y\|$ if and only if one of $x$ or $y$ is a non-negative scalar multiple of the other" which is independent of the strictly convex hypothesis. The proof goes as follows:

> If $x$ is the zero vector, then $\|x + y\| = \|x\| + \|y\|$ and $x = 0y$; likewise if $y = 0$. Suppose then that $x$ and $y$ are not the zero vector. Then $$\|x+y\|^2 = \langle x+ y, x+y\rangle = \langle x,x\rangle + \langle x,y\rangle + \langle y, x\rangle + \langle y, y\rangle = \|x\|^2 + 2\langle x, y\rangle + \|y\|^2.$$ On the other hand, if $\|x + y\| = \|x\| + \|y\|$, then $$\|x+y\|^2 = \|x\|^2+2\|x\|\|y\|+\|y\|^2.$$ Comparing the two expressions for $\|x+y\|^2$, we see that $\langle x, y\rangle = \|x\|\|y\|$. As $\langle x, y\rangle = \|x\|\|y\|\cos\theta$, we see that $\theta = 0$, i.e. $x$ and $y$ lie on the same ray, so $x = \lambda y$ for some $\lambda > 0$. Conversely, if $x = \lambda y$ for $\lambda > 0$, then $$\|x + y\| = \|x + \lambda x\| = |1+\lambda|\|x\| = \|x\| + \lambda\|x\| = \|x\| + \|\lambda x\| = \|x\| + \|y\|.$$

Comment: Where do you use the fact the norm is induced by an inner product?